# Ordering manually triggered jobs in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration

I'm in the process of setting up a build script for a CI pipeline in gitlab. I want the job to wait for manual input before running. I can't seem to find a configuration that works however. If I make one of the stages 'manual' the other stage will still run as soon as I push a change. If I use allow_failure: false as described here: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/05/20/dag-manual-fix/ the job hangs at pending once I trigger it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions?

For reference, my gitlab-ci-yml looks like:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build-dev:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - development
  script:
    - echo "building message center..."

deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - development
  variables:
    NODE1: "99099"
  script:
    - echo shutting down tomcat for node $NODE1...
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
```

Comment: Need some more clarity on your .gitlab-ci.yml file. So you have more stages after deploy. Do you want build to run automatically and deploy to be manual? And what about the rest after deploy? Can you add more details on how your pipeline looks and how you want the all stages to respond. I can help you out of you can provide more details.

Comment: @Raghu No. I have two stages, build and deploy, that should run in that order. When I check in code, I want the job to queue up but wait for manual input before any of the stages run. Once the job is actually started it should run through the build stage and then automatically run the deploy stage once build has suceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small modification as below it would work the way you wanted

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build-dev:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - development
  script:
    - echo "building message center..."
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - development
  variables:
    NODE1: "99099"
  script:
    - echo shutting down tomcat for node $NODE1...
```

Now, the moment you commit your code, the pipeline will be created but it will get blocked at build stage waiting for a manual start from you. Once manually triggered and if the build stage is successful, the deploy stage will automatically run.

Any failure in build stage will not let the deploy stage proceed. The status of deploy stage would be "skipped" in this case and you cannot run the deploy stage as build has failed.

Comment: That seems to work. I tried a similar configuration before but I must have had an error somewhere.